# $f$ is Riemann-integrable iff the region under its graph is Jordan-measurable

Tags: measure-theory, riemann-integration

Let $Q\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle and let $f: Q \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive function.

Let $\Gamma=\left \{ (x_1, ..., x_n, x_{n+1}): 0\leq x_{n+1}\leq f(x_1, ... , x_n) \right \}$.

Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable $\Leftrightarrow$  $\Gamma$ is Jordan-measurable.

The $\Rightarrow$ direction is quite easy: it's enough to observe that
$\partial\Gamma \subseteq G \cup (B_f\times[0, M]) \cup (\partial Q\times [0, M])$
where $G=\left \{ (x_1, ..., x_n, x_{n+1}): x_{n+1}= f(x_1, ... , x_n) \right \}$, $B_f$ is the set of discontinuities of $f$ and $M$ is a bound for $f$.
All three have measure 0 if $f$ is integrable.

But the other direction is harder. Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Bd}{\partial}\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$**Hint**: If your definition of [Jordan measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure#Extension_to_more_complicated_sets) coincides with Wikipedia's (i.e., "inner" and "outer" approximations have arbitrarily close area), then each lower sum for the [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Definition) is an "inner" approximation and every upper sum is an "outer" approximation.

---

**Edit**: The strategy is to cover the graph of $f$ by finitely many rectangles $R_{i}$ of small area, then to subdivide $Q$ into rectangles $Q_{j}$ so that each $R_{i}$ is *partitioned* (modulo overlapping boundaries) by its intersections with the "columns" $Q_{j} \times [0, M]$. Finally, over each $Q_{j}$, choose an interval $[m_{j}, M_{j}]$ so that

- $m_{j} \leq f(x) \leq M_{j}$ for all $x$ in $Q_{j}$, and
- $Q_{j} \times [m_{j}, M_{j}]$ is contained in the union of the $R_{i}$.

The corresponding approximations to the Riemann integral are arbitrarily close.

---

Since the details are potentially delicate, here's a sketch of the one-dimensional case, phrased in a way to facilitate generalization to arbitrarily many variables.

Let $Q$ be a closed interval, $f:Q \to \Reals$ a bounded function satisfying $0 \leq f(x) \leq M$ for all $x$, and
$$
\Gamma = \{(x, y) : 0 \leq f(x) \leq y,\ x \in Q\}
$$
the Jordan-measurable region under the graph of $f$.

Fix $\eps > 0$, and pick finitely many rectangles $R_{i} = [a_{i}, b_{i}] \times [c_{i}, d_{i}]$ (with $1 \leq i \leq I$, say) of total area at most $\eps/2$ whose union contains the graph $G$ of $f$. (Use the remaining $\eps/2$ of the "total error budget" to cover $(Q \times \{0\}) \cup (\Bd Q \times [0, M])$.) There exists a partition $P = (x_{j})_{j=0}^{J}$ of $Q$ such that for every $j = 1, \dots, J$ and for every $i = 1, \dots, I$, either $Q_{j} = [x_{j-1}, x_{j}]$ is contained in $[a_{i}, b_{i}]$, or else $(x_{j-1}, x_{j}) \cap (a_{i}, b_{i}) = \varnothing$. [Note 1]

For each $j$, let $m_{j}$ be the *largest* of the $c_{i}$ such that

- $Q_{j} \subset [a_{i}, b_{i}]$, and
- $c_{i} \leq f(x)$ for all $x$ in $Q_{j}$.

In words, $m_{j}$ is the height of the *highest lower edge* among rectangles lying over $Q_{j}$ that also lies on or below the graph of $f$ over $Q_{j}$.

Similarly, let $M_{j}$ be the *smallest* of the $d_{i}$ such that $Q_{j} \subset [a_{i}, b_{i}]$ and $f(x) \leq d_{i}$ for all $x$ in $Q_{j}$. [Note 2]

Consequently, [Note 3]
$$
U(f, P) - L(f, P)
= \sum_{j=1}^{N} (M_{j} - m_{j})(x_{j} - x_{j-1})
\leq \sum_{i=1}^{I} (d_{i} - c_{i})(b_{i} - a_{i})
< \eps/2.
\tag{*}
$$
In words, the [Darboux sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral) can be made closer than $\eps/2$ for arbitrary $\eps > 0$, so $f$ is Riemann integrable over $Q$.

Notes:

1. In the one-dimensional case, take $P = (x_{j})$ to be the sorted union of the division points $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$. Generally, subdivide this way "in each variable". Geometrically, cover the graph of $f$ with finitely many boxes $R_{i}$ of total volume at most $\eps/2$. Project away the $(n+1)$th coordinate, and take the smallest grid subdivision of $Q$ that contains the shadows of the $R_{i}$.
2. Each $Q_{j}$ is contained in at least one $[a_{i}, b_{i}]$, and by construction is completely contained in every $[a_{i}, b_{i}]$ whose interior intersects $Q_{j}$. Because the $R_{i} = [a_{i}, b_{i}] \times [c_{i}, d_{i}]$ cover the graph of $f$, for each $j$, there exists an $i$ such that $c_{i} \leq f(x)$ for all $x$ in $Q_{j}$, and there exists an $i'$ such that $f(x) \leq d_{i'}$ for all $x$ in $Q_{j}$.
3. By construction, for each $j = 1, \dots, J$ we have $m_{j} \leq f(x) \leq M_{j}$ for all $x$ in $Q_{j}$. The first equality in (*) follows since the $Q_{j}$ have disjoint interiors.

   By construction, $Q_{j} \times [m_{j}, M_{j}] \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{I} [a_{i}, b_{i}] \times [c_{i}, d_{i}]$, so
   $$
   \bigcup_{j=1}^{J} Q_{j} \times [m_{j}, M_{j}] \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{I} [a_{i}, b_{i}] \times [c_{i}, d_{i}],
   $$
   which gives the first inequality in (*).

Comment: We have to equivalent defintions: 1. If the indicator function $\chi _ A$ is riemann integrable. 2. If the boundry has measure 0.

Comment: Not sure if you're saying either of those two conditions is your definition of "$A$ is Jordan measurable", or if their equivalence is a theorem you can use; in any event, the condition "the boundary of $\Gamma$ has content zero" clearly implies "'inner' and 'outer' approximations of $\Gamma$ have arbitrarily close content", which is enough to establish from the definition that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: I meant that these were the two ways we've seen to characterize jordan-measurable functions. But you're right, I believe I figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: I still don't get it. If we know $\Gamma$ is jordan measurable, then we only know that *there are* inner and outer approximations. No one promises us that these approximations look like the ones you get from riemann upper and lower sums. And I can't see how can we "turn" them into ones. Could you please elaborate?